# Messages sat in Outbox - won't send and cannot be deleted

Tags: email, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, outlook-2007

We have SBS 2008 running Exchange 2007. Our clients are running Outlook 2007.

For one user there are items in the Outbox that are not sending, they're just sitting there. If I try to delete them, nothing happens. No error message. I have full control over the mailbox (thus why I'm able to see it) so I should be able to delete them.

On the server-side, no errors appear in Event Viewer and we've been sending/receive other emails no problem all day/night.

Any idea what would cause this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OST corruption can cause this, which is solved by deleting the OST and letting a new one resync. The act of deleting the OST may also delete the hung messages too, if they did not have a chance to sync up to the server yet.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off cached mode, move/delete the OST, restart, see if in the outbox, shouldn't be, turn back on cached mode.